# Make a new shapefile from parts of two shapefiles

Tags: qgis

I have tried all day to connect two shapefiles, crop a part of them, and save it into a new Shapefile.

In the image you can see two Shapefiles and inside of the square is the part which I want to export into a new shapefile.

It is possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to save a) the points and b) the polygons in the square as separate files? Or do you want to save the points that are within the polygon?

Comment: everything which is in the squar

Comment: Put the clipping geometry on a new layer and use Geoalgorithms-Vector-Overlay-Clip.

Comment: Why not creating two? 1) Points and 2) part of polygons that are inside of the rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to store points and lines together in one Shapefile - as your question suggests - you can stop trying because it is simply not possible to mix geometries in this format.

Depending on your requirements, either use two Shapefiles or switch to Spatialite to save both layers in one database file.